# error in installing opencv with CUDA - opencv_cudaarithm Error

Tags: python, opencv, cuda, cmake, makefile

Is there somebody who knows how to solve this problem: having already done cmaking using ccmake.., in making step using make -j7 got this error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so
[ 38%] Built target opencv_cudaarithm
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

appreciate it if you could help me  out!
I used the cmake below:

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/<user>/opencv 
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/<user>/anaconda/bin/python2.7 
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/<user>/anaconda/include/python2.7 
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/<user>/anaconda/include/python2.7 
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=/home/<user>/anaconda/include/python2.7 
-D PYTHON_LIBRARIES=/home/<user>/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so 
-D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/<user>/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so 
-D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/<user>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
-D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/home/<user>/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so 
-D PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/<user>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON 
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON 
-D MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/<user>/MATLAB/extern/include 
-D MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS=/home/<user>/MATLAB/bin 
-D MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT=/home/<user>/MATLAB/bin 
-D MATLAB_ROOT_DIR=/home/<user>/MATLAB ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and its solution. 
Becuase my OS is 64 bit, I should've used a different  configuration for the ffmpeg and x264 installations. I used the guidance in the following link and managed to install Opencv without any more problems.

http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/

Answer (score 0):

One thing I usually check is the makefile that cmake generated. Another thing to check is the CMakeCache file. Check if the directories are been correctly set.

Comment: I chechek everything and changed my cmake to the one added to my question. still have problem. shall I reinstall cuda?

Comment: thanks there is no need anymore. I found out what was the problem which I put it below